# adding 1 to each element of an array

Tags: ruby

i tred creating a method called "Sum_plus_one" that accepts an array argument containing integers. Themethod should return the sum of the integers in the array after adding one to each of them.

example:
   sum_plus_one([1,2,3])

result should be: 9

my code looks like this

```
def sum_plus_one(*nums)

     for num in nums
     num + 1
     end
     total = 0
     for num in nums
     total += num
     end
 return total
end
```

Comment: `num + 1` has no effect on the contents of the array.

Comment: thanks for the reply i'm still a newbie in Ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map/reduce is handy here:

```
def sum_plus_one(nums)
  nums.map(&:succ).reduce(:+)
end
```

Edit:

here is one way to make your code work:

```
def sum_plus_one(nums)
  nums.map! do |num|
    num + 1
  end

  total = 0
  for num in nums
    total += num
  end

  return total
end
```

Comment: wow it really help me thanks a lot, but what does the map function do?

Comment: map is an iterator. It changes each element in the array according to the code in the block(`do |num| num + 1 end`). In this case it adds 1 to each element in the array. We tend to use iterators in Ruby. It relieves us from keeping track of i's and j's and makes for clean, succinct, flexible code. See the map/reduce example above for comparison.

Answer (score 5):

Why not do a little bit of math beforehand and see that summing the array-elements-plus-one is the same as summing the elements and then adding the array length? For example:

```
(5+1) + (6+1) + (11+1) = 5 + 6 + 11 + (1 + 1 + 1)
                       = 5 + 6 + 11 + 3
```

That gives you something nice and simple:

```
array.inject(:+) + array.length
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

```
[105] pry(main)> arr
=> [1, 2, 3]
[106] pry(main)> arr.inject(0) { |var, i| var + i + 1 }
=> 9
```

So the method would look like

```
def sum_plus_one(*nums)
  nums.inject(0) { |var, num| var + num + 1 }
end
```

Comment: it is sufficient to return `var + num + 1` without assigning it to `var`.

Answer (score 1):

Functional Style Version

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce(0) {|acc, n| acc + n + 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you need to assign your `num + 1` value to the corresponding element of the array that you are enumerating in the first loop.

maybe something like this:

```
for i in (0...nums.count)
    nums[i] += 1
end
```

after that your program should work

(yes, you can use fancy libraries or constructs instead of the above loop)

please note that you can eliminate the top loop and just add `num + 1` to your `total` in the second loop.